# Generate a table of lat/long coordinates from addresses on Google Maps efficiently?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there an efficient way to generate/fetch the corresponding (lat/long) coordinates from a table of addresses for Google Maps?

Our usual way is to query per row through Google Maps API which consumes 1 request allowed (current usage plan is 3000 requests per day) and we have 700+ rows to generate every week so we wanted to optimize the usage.

I read somewhere that I can do this through fusion tables which returns JSON data which I could easily convert for database, but I don't have any idea how to do so with fusion tables. Other than that, all other way are most welcome.

Comment: Someone downvoted without bothering to even explain what's wrong.

Comment: If you want to know Fusion Table, then try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer) that show how to use Fusion Tables in Google Maps API. It allows you to render data contained in Fusion Tables as a layer on a map using the `FusionTablesLayer` object. A Fusion Table is a database table where each row contains data about a particular feature; for geographic data, each row within a Fusion Table additionally contains location data, holding a feature’s positional information. Just check the documentation for more information.